# Expose Windows PowerShell Commands as REST call

Tags: windows, rest, powershell

I'm not familiar with Windows OS but I have some PowerShell commands I want to execute but I need to expose them as REST call. I'm not sure what the easiest but secure method to do that.
My environment is mostly LAMP with multiple REST applications. I would like to not have to do anything special to the front end client that uses these applications.

Comment: Two good links to help you : [RESTful Server by Parul](http://poshcode.org/4073) and [PowerShell Web Server](http://www.poshserver.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the code in this blog post almost verbatim to easily expose PowerShell cmdlets directly via REST:
[Exposing PowerShell as a JSON-Emitting, REST-Like Web Service](http://powershill.blogspot.com/2011/08/exposing-powershell-as-web-service.html)

This is a C# ASP.Net web app that you would run in IIS.

It's interesting for something general purpose, but I think a better method is to write your own. Using ASP.Net is ideal because you have access to runspaces, which are natively executing PowerShell code (as opposed to some janky thing where you shell out to PowerShell.exe or something like that).

Writing your own let's you decide how to structure the API exactly the way you want.

Even when I used the above code, I wrote my own PowerShell module and exposed only those functions I wrote myself for this purpose.

You might also have a look at [PowerShell Pipeworks](http://powershellpipeworks.com/), which looks very promising but I've not had a chance to play with it.